# SQL: efficient way to do calculations on data in a long format

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table of male and female counts by item, as in:

[image]

I am looking to calculate the proportion of males by item, such that the output would look like:

```
ITEM  PROP_MALE
A     0.3
B     0.5
```

In R, I would `dcast` gender into a wide format and then divide male count over total once M/F are in the same row. But in SQL, I am struggling to find an efficient solution (If it helps, I am using Oracle SQL).

Comment: Have a look at `ratio_to_report`

Answer (score 1):

I would do this simply using `sum()` and division:

```
select item,
       sum(case when gender = 'M' then n else 0 end) / sum(n) as male_ratio
from t
group by item;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `RATIO_TO_REPORT`:

```
SELECT ITEM, PROP_MALE
FROM  (SELECT ITEM, gender,
       RATIO_TO_REPORT(N) OVER (PARTITION BY Item) AS PROP_MALE
      FROM tab) sub
WHERE sub.gender = 'M';
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=83091bd508601f4c0dd6c8654e1c0a87)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SUM` analytic function:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/94efb/6)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( item , gender, n ) AS
SELECT 'A', 'M',  30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'F',  70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'M', 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'F', 100 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Item,
       n / total AS prop_male
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         SUM( n ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Item ) AS total
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  gender = 'M'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/94efb/6/0)**:

```
| ITEM | PROP_MALE |
|------|-----------|
|    A |       0.3 |
|    B |       0.5 |
```

You can even do the calculation directly on the table with the uncounted values:

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name_pre_count ( item , gender ) AS
SELECT 'A', 'M' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  30 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'F' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  70 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'M' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'F' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100;
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT Item,
       prop_male
FROM   (
  SELECT item,
         gender,
         COUNT(*) / SUM( COUNT(*) ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Item )
           AS prop_male
  FROM   table_name_pre_count
  GROUP BY Item, Gender
)
WHERE  gender = 'M'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/94efb/6/1)**:

```
| ITEM | PROP_MALE |
|------|-----------|
|    A |       0.3 |
|    B |       0.5 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table gender
(
  item varchar(10),
  gender varchar(10),
  val decimal(3,1)
  );
 insert into gender values ('A','M',30) ;
 insert into gender values ('A','F',70) ;
 with cte as
(
  select item,val,gender,
  sum(val) over(order by val) as calc
  from gender
  ),
cte1 as 
  (
  select item,
  case when gender='M' then val/calc end as prop_male
  from cte)
  select * from cte1
  where PROP_MALE is not null
```